# how do I add 1 to var

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add (+1) to return value of var interval?

I have a slider and everything is working using below code. I just wanted to set the min attr to interval + 1. so if interval value is 2 I wanted to make it 3 on min attr. thanks

```
var $slider = $('input[name="notification_interval"]');

$slider.on('change', function() {
    var interval = $(this).val();

    $("#maxshift").attr("min", interval);

    $("#maxshift").change();


});
```

follow up question: Is it possible to add (+1) to var interval upto 24 only?

Comment: Parse it as integer.

Comment: If $('input[name="notification_interval"]') contains a number value you can just add interval + 1;

Answer (score 3):

You should parse the *numeral* (a string) to add 1 as follows:

```
interval = $('input[name="notification_interval"]').val();
interval = parseInt(interval, 10) + 1;
                              ^^ ATTENTION HERE
```

The base of 10 in the `parseInt()` invocation is necessary. Don't use `parseInt()` ever without the base!

It is necessary to parse the numeral to a number because the `+` operator is overloaded and has a different semantic depending on the type of the addends:

```
"hello" + 1  => "hello1"
```

This example shows how a string is concatenated with the `1`, which is a number but will be coerced to string before the concatenation.

There's a *reticule* (priority map) that specifies exactly how type coercion is performed when mixed types are used.

To be really short about it, just use `parseInt()` on strings to have an arithmetical addition.

Comment: thank you sir. follow up question: Is it possible to add (+1) to var interval upto 24 only?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, maybe you want to have `interval` to be limited from `0` to `23`? You can do this with `interval = (parseInt(interval, 10) + 1) % 24;`. For values from `1` to `24` use `interval = (parseInt(interval, 10) + 1) % 24 + 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers allready state why and how you should use `parseInt()`.

If I understand your 'follow up question' right, you want to stop incrementing that `interval` at value of 24.

You can achieve it many ways. One would be using `if`-statement e.g.

```
interval = parseInt(interval, 10);

if (interval < 24) { 
  $("#maxshift").attr("min", interval + 1);
}
```

Or you could do it with `Math.min()`, e.g. with this one-liner:

```
$("#maxshift").attr("min", Math.min(24, parseInt(interval, 10) + 1));
```

The first one expresses the intention very explicitly.
The second is shorter and somewhat tricky to understand, but its also somewhat 'more secure' if `interval` would already be greater than 24.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#maxshift").attr("min", parseInt(interval, 10) + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure `parseInt` is needed here. Please explain in your answer why you added it.

Comment: Type safety.  If `interval` is a string "1", then `interval + 1` = "11".   (Off the top of my head I can't remember if `.val()` would return a string or an int, though)

Comment: val() returns string. I'm trying to find a reference somewhere to confirm that.

Comment: follow up question: Is it possible to add (+1) to var interval upto 24 only?

Comment: If you're going to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) make sure you also pass in the radix: `parseInt(interval, 10)` -- other wise it will try to parse anything starting with a leading `0` as octal or hex.